# Is there a Node JS equivalent to Bash exec?

Tags: node.js

There are times when I want to exit a NodeJS script and hand over all control of the terminal to another program just like Bash's `exec` command.  This behavior is shown below using the simple  `t.sh:`

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 5; exec /usr/bin/vlc
```

We can start `t.sh` and then press **ctrl-z** to suspend the process and inspect the PID:

```
ps -elf |grep t.sh |grep -v grep |awk '{print $4}' # prints 10554
```

We can then resume the process using `fg` and, after VLC starts, press **ctrl-z** once again and inspect the PID of VLC:

```
ps -elf |grep vlc |grep -v grep |awk '{print $4}' # prints 10554
```

We can see VLC has replaced `t.sh` altogether using the PID.  I very much want the same behavior with Node JS but am haven't discovered the magic yet.

Something like this would be perfect: `process.exit( '/usr/bin/vlc' );`  Of course, that doesn't work. I am already using `child_process.spawn` and `child_process.exec` and `process.exit` in other capacities. Unless I'm missing something, these don't appear to be able to do a classic Bash `exec`.  Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

node does not have any built-in access to the necessary APIs (as they are not portable to Windows), but there are a few packages that provide native bindings: [execpe](https://www.npmjs.com/package/execpe), [native-exec](https://www.npmjs.com/package/native-exec).

Comment: Thanks, Josh!  "Doesn't work on Windows" isn't a deal breaker since the app will never be deployed to that environment.  In other cases, the exec allows provides a stop-gap solution that gives me time to migrate bash shell scripts to NodeJS.

Comment: Both native-exec and execpe appear forked from https://github.com/jprichardson/node-kexec.  While native-exec is more popular, execpe looks more capable.